# Local Timer Object Event Handler

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have the following code in a class function :

```
public function foo():void
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000,1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,onTimerComplete);
    timer.start();
}

public function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The above code works most of the time but my concern is what happens if timer gets garbage collected? Is it possible that onTimerComplete will never fire because there are no other references to timer?

I know timer has an internal list of handlers but that won't keep it from being GC'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some references on the web to running timers never being garbage collected, [e.g.](http://osflash.org/pipermail/osflash_osflash.org/2008-February/014893.html):

> Just to be clear: even if you have no references to a Timer, as long
> as the timer is running, it will not be Garbage Collected (think of
> it as if the runtime was keeping a reference to running timers).
>
> by Arno Gourdol on the Adobe AIR Team

but I haven't been able to find an authoritative source.

Probably best to not rely on this special behavior and instead make `timer` a class-level variable, though.

Answers suggesting that event listeners are keeping the timer from being garbage collected are incorrect.  The reference is from the timer to the listener function (`onTimerComplete`), so if the timer is reachable then the listener function won't be garbage collected, but not vice versa.  This is easily tested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
private var _gcTimer:Timer;

protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(30, 4);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer, false, 0, true);
    
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onSprite, false, 0, true);
    
    _gcTimer = new Timer(59, 1);
    _gcTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, garbageCollect);

    timer.start();
    _gcTimer.start();
}

private function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("timer");
}

private function onSprite(event:Event):void {
    trace("sprite");
}
]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Output:

> sprite
> timer
> sprite
> timer
> Collecting garbage
> timer
> timer

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is garbage collection, can you just put the timer into an array to keep reference to it?

```
var antiGarbage:Array = [];
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000, 1);

antiGarbage[antiGarbage.length] = timer;
```

I don't think there's a concern though, pretty sure you would have to do:

```
timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
```

For the timer to be ready for GC.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what your timer is doing is calling the onTimerComplete method once anyway so why care if it is GCed.
In any case you are playing with something very close to a JavaScipt closure. A closure is a function that has lost its scope. When something loses scope it becomes very hard to GC it, especially since you still have an event listener attached to it. Pointless in your case because it is only running once.
Good coding practices would be to null out the object after you are done with it.

Also, one more thing about your code.
This is wrong.

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE,onTimerComplete);
```

Should be

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLET,onTimerComplete);
```

If you move the timer object to the class scope it will not be GCed.

```
public var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000,1);
public function foo():void
{
    this.timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,this.onTimerComplete);
    this.timer.start();
}

public function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: My concern is if the delay on the timer is too long, lets say thousands of seconds is there the possibility that the timer gets garbage collected and the onTimerComplete never gets called.

Comment: it should not be  GCed untill the event listener is removed.

Comment: Are you sure about that? This article : http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/ states that listeners do not keep dispatchers from being GC'ed.

Comment: And come to think about it the class that these function reside in(and the parent of that and the parent of the....) will not be GCed either until the timer goes away. So as you can see your method is a bad practice.

Comment: please read this section particularly about the useWeakReference parameter http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29

Comment: That article states that onTimerComplete doesnt keep the timer from being GC collected. I dont know what is preventing it from being GC collected. there are no references to it in the application. I guess this line in the adobe documentation explains it. "Objects with registered event listeners are not automatically removed from memory because the garbage collector does not remove objects that still have references. " In this case the timer object has a strong reference to the onTimerCOmplete function which keeps it from being garbage collected. Am I right?

Comment: I just profiled a sample app with the flash delevoped and "it should not be GCed untill the event listener is removed." is not the case. I created 500 timers and observed the profiler window and after sometime all those 500 timers were gone. I didn't call removeEventListener. Here is the sample code I used : http://pastebin.com/6u3ic3Ud

Comment: It is probably GCed because it lost its scope and the timer is no longer running. But isn't a good thing? Why would you want to force an object to not be GCed when that object is completely finished?

Comment: It is a good thing that it gets GC'ed when the timer ends and the event fires. What is even better is that you don't have to call removeEventListener on timer because apparantly that doesn't keep the timer from being GC'ed. I will try it with other objects and event handlers too see how it behaves.

Comment: Would be interested in your findings. I am leaning towards the timer being GCed because its done and doesn't have a scope. Another thing to test is see if the timer gets GCed during an infinite loop while it is running.

Comment: Surely its good practice to make it a class level variable and null it later when it is no longer needed. It is the developers responsibilty then and there are no ambiguitys to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the antiGarbage array unless you've already seen a problem and that magically solves it because it adds extra complexity to deal with 12 months from now.

I haven't had any trouble with event AS3 listeners and event dispatchers failing to connect with each other as long as objects were created.  One important gotchya to watch out for is creating an object that is stuck waiting (listening) for something that was already dispatched earlier in the initialization and so it missed the call (dispatched event) and hangs indefinitely.

If your Timer shows up in the debugger variables when it is supposed to be ticking and completing then you should be golden.