# event chain or stack too long as3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, events

I don't think "Chain" is the right word here. But this is my problem:

I have a que of 1000 items that need to be downloaded.

I use a loader with an event: Event.COMPLETE calls a function. 
This function creates a loader with an event which on Event.COMPLETE calls that function again ... etc.

This has never been an issue. I never even knew it meant that it would all be stacked up in memory.

On iOS this is proving to be an issue. At a certain maximum, it just tells me I've reached the limit. So at 500 I insert a Timer so that I can start calling these functions from "level 0 " again.

Now, I think my architecture is wrong here. What is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: is it possible to use ActionScript on iOS? is it not in violation of their license?

Comment: @Bshirely: Flash will convert Actionscript to native code of some sorts. So technically once it is in the app store or on a device there is no Actionscript to speak of.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially using a recursive call to perform your operations, which leaves memory on the stack. (This is generally covered lower-level in languages like C, and C++.) You need to rewrite your functions as iterative calls so that they will automatically be removed from the stack - you may try a for loop, or something of that sort.

Post your code - I'll rewrite an alternative that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all: why do you need to download 1000 items?
do you also have to show these items all at the same time?

suggestion 1)
maybe combining them into one *.zip file and downloading just this one file is an option ...
(http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/actionscript-class-library-fzip.html)
unzip it and access the files locally.

suggestion 2)
if not, maybe you can reuse the existing `Loader` instance after it loaded the file completely. and save the result somewhere else

suggestion 3)
maybe the problem is, that the old `Loader` instances aren't removed from memory. remember to remove all eventlisteners from the `Loader` so that the GC can take care of them.

Comment: On suggestion 3, note that *having* an event listener doesn't prevent being GC'd.  It's the listener function (the 2nd argument to `addEventListener`) that won't be GC'd while the object it's a registered listener for is still reachable.

Comment: you sure about that? i thought because of the reference the object keeps of the listener the object also doesn't get GC'd ... !?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891354/actionscript-3-local-timer-object-event-handler/8736214#8736214) where I offer up some test code to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3071138 Unfortunately, had to post this several times already. This well may be Loader's bug. In any case, iOS target is very fresh, and is probably more buggy then the rest.

This is not, however, a stack overflow error, because event handlers called in response to loader's "complete" event are asynchronous (each one opens a new stack frame). I'm not sure it is possible to solve the issue at the moment.